# Fire callback within function

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I am trying to create my first own jQuery function to re-order some rows in a table.

The function works fairly well, I am just unsure how to fire the callback functions which i should be able to set in the settings object. Also is this the way to make a jQuery function? The code can be seen in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/fcHQh/

The function is:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.reorder = function(options) {

        var settings = {
            'up': '.up',
            'down': '.down',
            'timeout': 1000,
            'url': '',
            'success': null,
            'error': null
        };

        var methods = {
            init : function(element) {
                $(settings.up + ',' + settings.down).on('click', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
                    if ($(this).is(settings.up)) {
                        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
                    } else {
                        row.insertAfter(row.next());
                    }
                    tools.delay(function() { methods.sort(element) }, settings.timeout);
                });
            },
            sort : function(element) {
                $(element).find('tr').find('input:hidden').each(function () {
                    element.priorities.push($(this).val());
                }); 
                if (settings.url) {
                    methods.callback(element);
                }
            },
            callback : function(element) {
                            // THIS SHOULD ONLY BE FIRED IF CALLBACK IS DEFINED?
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: settings.url,
                    data: { priorities: element.priorities.join(',') },
                    success: function() {
                    // FIRE THE 'settings.success' if its set
                    },
                    error: function() {
                    // FIRE THE 'settings.error' if its set 
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        var tools = {
            delay : (function () {
                var timer = 0;
                return function (callback, ms) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
                };
            })()
        } 

        return this.each(function() {
            if (options) $.extend(settings, options);
            this.priorities = [];
            methods.init(this);
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you have a defaults object, and merge that with your options:

```
var defaults = {
  up: '.up',
  down: '.down',
  timeout: 1000,
  url: '',
  success: function() {},
  error: function() {}
};

var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

// ...
callback: function() {
  $.ajax({
    success: settings.success,
    error: settings.error
  });
},
// ...
```

Comment: The gist is that you don't want to overwrite your defaults, and possibly not the options passed, but you want to create a copy where you have your defaults, and if present, your options. $.extend achieves that.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: And here is a good primer on writing jQuery plugins: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant by // THIS SHOULD ONLY BE FIRED IF CALLBACK IS DEFINED? - I figured you wanted to control that with some setting?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. I was a comment for my head. I have it figured out now and it works - thank you!